# Cannot cat or grep contents of file

Tags: files, text, newlines

I'm on Debian Jessie. When I open a new textfile with `mousepad` and save it, then modify it with `vim` and save it again, I cannot print or `grep` the contents of it anymore.

If I do `cat file`, nothing is shown in the terminal. If I open `file` with `vim` or `mousepad`, I see the contents. If I write the file with `vim`, the following is shown in the status line:

```
"file" [mac] 2L, 5C written
```

While for a "normal" file, I only get

```
"file" 2L, 5C written
```

I thought the `[mac]` had something to do with the formatting of the new lines, so I tried to run:

```
dos2unix file
```

but the problem persists. Does anyone know what exactly is wrong with the file?

Comment: `vim` actually has a built-in option for this. Simply run [`:set ff=unix`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format) to convert the file you are currently editing to use LF-only line endings. Then, overwrite the file with `:w`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `recode`, e.g.: `recode /cr file`

Note: the fact that you can see the contents in the terminal with `cat file` is that the Mac end-of-line is CR, which puts the cursor at the beginning of the line without going to the next line, so that everything gets overwritten.

Comment: I'm wondering why the OP had the pre OSX old Mac CR format in the first place given that he's on Debian; a misconfiguration of mousepad perhaps?